# EventSource events show empty in Windows Performance Analyzer

Tags: c#, etw, etw-eventsource, eventsource

I can successfully generate ETW events with [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) in a C# console app; however if I store the events in a an ETL file and use Windows Performance Analyzer, the columns corresponding to the payload values, the event name and the provider name show are empty.

**QUESTION**

Are there any extra configurations for the EventSource that would allow the columns in WPA to get populated?

**Notes:**

- There is another question posted here: "How do you view ETW events created by EventSource using Windows Performance Analyzer?", I believe that that question is not a duplicate of mine, as I can see the rows representing the events in WPA, it's just that the events are empty.
- If I analyze the ETL with PerView.exe, I can see that the raw data for the event is present
- If I create the event from C++ using a library I have at hand, the resulting ETW events show correctly in WPA
- Having empty columns in WPA is not a big issue, my real problem is that a second application written in C++ that is expecting the events to have a payload and an event name is not being able to identify the events. I believe that the empty columns in WPA and the C++ app not being to identify the events are two related symptoms, and given that the WPA having empty columns is something that anyone could reproduce by simply running the steps I describe below, that's why I mentioned that issue as the main symptom in the introduction of my question.

**Minimal code:**

```
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
namespace EtwConsoleApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            MyEventSource.Instance.MyEvent("x");
            MyEventSource.Instance.MyEvent("y");
            MyEventSource.Instance.MyEvent("z");
        }
    }

    [EventSource(Guid = "56ff7ff6-0418-4501-945f-c12737bc1c70")]
    sealed class MyEventSource : EventSource {
        [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Verbose, Opcode = EventOpcode.Info)]
        public void MyEvent(string value) {
            this.WriteEvent(1, value);
        }

        public static MyEventSource Instance = new MyEventSource();
    }
}
```

**See the empty rows in WPA:**

- Open an elevated CMD
- logman create trace MySession -p {56ff7ff6-0418-4501-945f-c12737bc1c70} -o MySession.etl
- logman start MySession
- Run C# console application
- logman stop MySession
- Open the ETL with WPA, you will see the three rows corresponding to the three events from the code, however the rows are empty
- Open the ETL with PerfView, you will see that the raw data is present (you can dump an event to the console in PerfView by pressing ALT+D when the event is selected)

Comment: which WPA version do you use? Try the WPA from Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: @maciandre1981 I'm using the WPA from the latest Windows 10 SDK, the version of my WPA is 10.0.10586. I believe the issue is not WPA, but instead with the way the ETW events get generated.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Tracing shows that you use the inbox version. try the Nuget version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource

Comment: have you tried the nuget version?

Comment: also try to capture the Events via **xperf.exe -start UserLogger -on 56ff7ff6-0418-4501-945f-c12737bc1c70 -buffersize 4096 -f User.etl   xperf.exe -stop UserLogger xperf.exe -merge User.etl kernel.etl Result.etl -compress**

Comment: I voted to close the question as **too broad** because you never gave any feedback to suggestions and without this we can't help you.

Comment: I added the solution I finally used. Which was to use the Nuget version: Micrsofot.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource

Answer (score 1):

System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource from .NET 4.5 does not produce events that are correctly visualized by WPA.

Solution was to use:
Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource

Another solution is to use:
System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource from .NET 4.6 (which in my case was not possible)

Comment: posting the solution from others is not the best idea ;)

Comment: What's your problem? I surfaced the solution for whoever needs it in the future, I do not want benefit or anything like that, I just want to help. Also, consider that by having voted -1 on the solution, just because you "think" I am trying to steal the answer is demoting a good solution with reasons that are not related to the correctness of the solution per se. Be more objective in the future.

Comment: The correct way of you would be saying, ok the nuget version helped, post it as answer and I mark it as answer. in the future I'll simply ignore you and no longer answer.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.Tracing` shows that you use the inbox version of the .net framework 4.5. Try the Nuget version [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource) which gets updated more often to get new features.